# Segue.destinationViewController is set to value of sourceViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm learning about iOS as I write an application that uses a UITableViewController and Core Data to display a list of items, and another view controller that also uses Core Data to configure a variety of additional attributes that are not shown in the table view.

A button in the UITableViewController's navigation bar segues to another view that lets me set a variety of details. This is done using a storyboard  "Show Detail" segue, and it works fine.

I want to use the accessory action button in a UITableViewCell to segue to the same detail view controller, so I created another "Show Detail" segue in the storyboard that connects the accessory detail button to the detail view controller (ie: the same kind of segue as the button in the navigation bar)

Confusingly, when I click the detail accessory button at run time, nothing happens, and prepareForSegue is never called.

The UITableView cell style is Subtitle, and I've configured it to have a Detail accessory action. However, the accessory button isn't displayed unless I specifically add it:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: Storyboard.reuseID)
        let tone = toneTable[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = tone.valueForKey("toneName") as? String          
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = tone.valueForKey("toneDescription") as? String
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton
    return cell
```

I finally gave up, and called prepareForSeque myself:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let tone = toneTable[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowToneDetail", sender: tone)
    }
```

(I'm using the sender parameter as a convenient place to pass an NSManagedOject)

Now, prepareForSegue gets called, but if I put a breakpoint in prepareForSegue, I see that segue.destinationViewController points to the the source view controller, not the destination view controller. This is unfortunate, because I'd like to pass some values to the new instance of the destinationViewController.

Interestingly, the segue does correctly instantiate the destinationViewController, and passes control to it.

But, I don't understand what's going on. I don't know why I have to call prepareForSeque myself, and I don't know why the segue's destinationViewController isn't set correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

ps: is it just my perception, or is XCode less mature than other IDEs like Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating your cells in the wrong way. You should be using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: to dequeue a cell using the identifier you setup in the storyboard. By doing it the way you are, you're directly instantiating a cell that "knows" nothing about the cell in the storyboard where you added the detail disclosure button, or the segue you made.

I have no idea why the segue.destinationViewController would point to the source view controller. My guess is that it doesn't, and maybe you have your controller classes mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!    Interestingly, when I switch to tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, the cell forgets the style that it was assigned in the storyboard, and has neither a detailTextLabel nor a disclosure accessory.

Comment: The segue.destinationViewController is incorrect when I look at the debugger's instance variables (I would have attached a screen shot here, but it looks like that's not allowed in the Add Comment field). However, I can successfully cast it to the destinationViewController class, so I'm chalking this up to an XCode anomaly.

Comment: @Andromeda That could be; the debugger sometimes gives spurious results. You could check it while debugging with `po segue.destinationViewController`, or log it in prepareForSegue.

Comment: True - the debugger defaulted the type to the current view controller, but it was fine after type conversion.